# Probability of getting 30 red balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have a box with $100$ red balls and $500$ white balls and I randomly remove 30 balls from this box. What is the probability of getting all $30$ balls red?

If I remove one ball, the probability of getting a red ball is $100/600$. If I then remove another one, without putting the first one back in the box, the probability of getting this second ball red is now $99/599$. By induction, I concluded that the probability of getting $30$ balls red is:
$$\frac{100}{600}\times \frac{99}{599} \times \frac{98}{598}\cdots \times \frac{71}{531}\times \frac{70}{530}$$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Is it one by one? Or in one shot?

Comment: 100/600 is 1/6 that means if u removed 100 balls one by one (condition u put it back) evey sixth ball will be red

Comment: In just one shot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your calculation is not.  If we have already selected $k - 1$ of the $600$ balls, there are $600 - (k - 1) = 601 - k$ balls left to select, so the number of choices for the $k$th ball is $601 - k$.  Therefore, the number of elements in the sample space is
$$600 \cdot 599 \cdot 598 \cdots 572 \cdot 571$$
Similarly, if we have selected $k - 1$ of the $100$ red balls, there are $100 - (k - 1) = 101 - k$ red balls left to select, so the number of choices for the $k$th red ball is $101 - k$.  Therefore, the number of favorable cases is
$$100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98 \cdots 72 \cdot 71$$
Hence,
$$\Pr(30~\text{red balls}) = \frac{100}{600} \cdot \frac{99}{599} \cdot \frac{98}{598} \cdots \frac{72}{572} \cdot \frac{71}{571}$$

**Alternate method**

We are selecting $30$ of the $600$ balls, so there are $\binom{600}{30}$ elements in our sample space.  Our favorable cases are the selections in which we obtain $30$ of the $100$ red balls, of which there are $\binom{100}{30}$.  Hence, the probability that all $30$ of the selected balls are red is
$$\Pr(30~\text{red balls}) = \frac{\dbinom{100}{30}}{\dbinom{600}{30}}$$
where
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
is the number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set.